# How to draw image on a window?

Tags: windows, winapi, createwindow

I have created a window with createwindow() api using VS2005 in C++ on Windows Vista

My requirement is to draw an image (of any format) on that window. I am not using any MFC in this application.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

not exactly sure what is your problem: draw a bitmap on the form, or you would like know how to work with various image formats, or both. Anyways below is an example of how you could load a bitmap and draw it on the form:

```
HBITMAP hBitmap = NULL;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;

    switch (message)
    {
<...>

    case WM_CREATE:
        hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(hInst, L"c:\\test.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        PAINTSTRUCT     ps;
        HDC             hdc;
        BITMAP          bitmap;
        HDC             hdcMem;
        HGDIOBJ         oldBitmap;

        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        oldBitmap = SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmap);

        GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(bitmap), &bitmap);
        BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, bitmap.bmWidth, bitmap.bmHeight, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

        SelectObject(hdcMem, oldBitmap);
        DeleteDC(hdcMem);

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        DeleteObject(hBitmap);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

LoadImage loads an icon, cursor, animated cursor, or bitmap. Details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648045(VS.85).aspx)

For working with various images formats you can use Windows Imaging Component (see [IWICBitmapDecoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531153(VS.85).aspx)) or code from here [Loading JPEG and GIF pictures](http://www.arstdesign.com/articles/picloader.html) or 3rd party tools like [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) or [LeadTools](http://www.leadtools.com/)

hope this helps, regards

Comment: Hi Serge,

it solved my problem of drawing image on window.

thanks for the help.

but as this takes only bmp,cur and ico files, i need to work on converting png to bmp and then i will pass that bmp to this function

Comment: can anybody guide me in putting png image on window without using any MFC

Comment: If I can save someone a few minutes of searching around, I tried using this answer but it didn't work. After a while of poking I tried to change the sizeof(bitmap) to sizeof(BITMAP) and the code worked.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10. 

Heres the full line : GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), &bitmap);

Comment: Why bother saving the old HBITMAP and calling SelectObject again if you delete the DC immediately after?

Answer (score 10):

```
void LoadScreen(HWND hWnd) {
    RECT rect;
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
    HBRUSH brush = CreatePatternBrush((HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, L"file.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE));
    GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rect);
    FillRect(hdc, &rect, brush);
    DeleteObject(brush);
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
}
```

Comment: And the leaked HDC that was never released upon function exit?  Windows GDI rules 101: If you Get it, then Release it; if you Create it, then Delete it. You did this correctly with your brush (Create/Delete), but failed to do so with your client DC (Get/Release).

Comment: Ah, thanks :) I resolved it. Just added one line before closing the curly bracket.   ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);

Comment: Functionality wise, how does this compare to [serge_gubenko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1760571/3357935)?

Comment: I don't know, but I see that my solution is much simpler, clean and straight-forward

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>

HBITMAP hBitmap, hOldBitmap;
HDC hdc, hdcMem;
BITMAP bm;
HINSTANCE hI;
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
RECT rect;
RECT rc;

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(hI, "1.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
    GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), &bm);
    hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
    hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    hOldBitmap = SelectBitmap(hdcMem, hBitmap);
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
    return 0;

    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    //for dragging not only by the title, but also by any part of the window 
    ReleaseCapture();
    SendMessage(hWnd, 0xA1, 2, 0);
    break;
    case WM_PAINT:
    hdc=BeginPaint(hWnd,&ps);
    
    //overlay image with stretching to fit the window 
    GetClientRect(hWnd,&rect);
    SetStretchBltMode(hdc, STRETCH_HALFTONE);
    StretchBlt(hdc,0,0,rect.right,rect.bottom,
    hdcMem,0,0,bm.bmWidth,bm.bmHeight,SRCCOPY);
    
    EndPaint(hWnd,&ps);
    break;      


    case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
      
    DeleteDC(hdcMem);
    DeleteObject(hBitmap);
    DeleteObject(hOldBitmap);
    break;
    }
return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
 
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPInst, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
//copying a pointer to a running application instance (module)
hI=hInstance;

WNDCLASS wc;

wc.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wc.lpfnWndProc   = WindowProcedure;
wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject(LTGRAY_BRUSH);
wc.lpszClassName = "test_class";
wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;

RegisterClass(&wc);

HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(wc.lpszClassName, "Image Window", 
//window with title (overlapping window) 
WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
//window without title
//WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP | WS_SYSMENU | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN,
CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 500, 500, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
UpdateWindow(hWnd);

MSG msg;
while(GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
    DispatchMessage (&msg);
    TranslateMessage (&msg);
    }
UnregisterClass(wc.lpszClassName, hInstance);
return (int) msg.wParam;
}
```

[image]