# Draw an dual-dimensional array of HBITMAP with LoadImage() in Win32 with C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I used the code in this answer for a reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1760571

Some guidelines on how to modify it in order to draw a matrix of bitmaps or there are other methods for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the situation, it can make sense to draw your grid of bitmaps together into one big bitmap, then blit from there to the screen when you need to redraw your window. Especially if you need to draw a large number of small bitmaps, this can save quite a bit of time when the screen needs redrawing.