# Winapi: How to display screenshot on window using UpdateLayeredWindow

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, bitmap, window

I have been driving myself trying to do something that to me seems like it should be relatively straight forward,
I am trying to take a screenshot of specific window (With PrintWindow)
And Display the screenshot over new window (using CreateWindowEx and UpdateLayeredWindow)

The Logic :

TakeNotepadScreenShot->DrawOverWindow->DisplayWindow

something like :

```
1. Take Notepad Screenshot: 
HBITMAP hBmp = PrintWindow(FindWindow("notepad")); //Not Entire Screen, Only notepad

2. Create Window (As Canvas):
HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LAYERED, "WindowClassName", 0, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

3. Draw Notepad Image:
Draw_HBitmap_OverWindow(hBmp,hWnd);
//Using UpdateLayeredWindow

4. Show Window / Display Notepad Screenshot
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
```

See: [How to get screenshot of a window as bitmap object in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292757/how-to-get-screenshot-of-a-window-as-bitmap-object-in-c) << Thats How To Take Notepad ScreenShot

But how to display the image? (C++/Console Application/Empty Project)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw image on a window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748470/how-to-draw-image-on-a-window)

Comment: You can use [`UpdateLayeredWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-updatelayeredwindow) to assign the `HBITMAP` image to the window.  The window will maintain the image and paint it onscreen for you when needed.

Comment: Otherwise, you can subclass the window and manually handle the [`WM_PAINT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/wm-paint) message, by drawing the `HBITMAP`, via [`BitBlt()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-bitblt) or [`StretchBlt()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-stretchblt), onto the `HDC` returned by [`BeginPaint()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-beginpaint).

Comment: @RemyLebeau I tried too many times (to display printwindow over window), no success, you can give me a example code by chance?
thank u.

Comment: Have you try like `PrintWindow(FindWindow(NULL, "notepad"), GetDC(hWnd), 0);` ?

Comment: Is it necessary for you to use `UpdateLayeredWindow`?

Answer (score 0):

You'd better create a Windows Desktop Application.
I have add a "Print" Menu, Then Add
`PrintWindow(FindWindow(L"Notepad", L"xxx.txt - Notepad"), GetDC(hWnd), 0);`

.cpp:

```
// WindowsProject9.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "WindowsProject9.h"

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Place code here.

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_WINDOWSPROJECT9, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_WINDOWSPROJECT9));

    MSG msg;

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_WINDOWSPROJECT9));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_WINDOWSPROJECT9);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

//
//   FUNCTION: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   PURPOSE: Saves instance handle and creates main window
//
//   COMMENTS:
//
//        In this function, we save the instance handle in a global variable and
//        create and display the main program window.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);
   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE:  Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - process the application menu
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Parse the menu selections:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_ABOUT:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                break;
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            case ID_HELP_PRINT:
                PrintWindow(FindWindow(L"Notepad", L"xxx.txt - Notepad"), GetDC(hWnd), 0);
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

[image]
[image]

EDIT:

I have uploaded the project on my onedrive, [this](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AuuE71XVcHDogTwjTpK7n772BjZD) is the link.

Comment: Thank You Drake! , WindowsProject9.h is missing : error C2065: 'IDI_WINDOWSPROJECT9' : undeclared identifie

Comment: I have uploaded the project to my onedrive, see edit in my answer.

Comment: it works, thanks !,  There is something else I want to ask: i want to set grayscale effect to the HBITMAP, how can i do this? How can i SetPixel?
PrintWindow(hWnd,GetDC(hWnd),0); works great , but i want to change the bitmap data LockBitmap LockBits, thanks =].

Comment: HWND hWnd = FindWindow(TEXT("Notepad"), NULL);
HBITMAP NotepadGray = grayscale(PrintWindow(hWnd,GetDC(hWnd),0));
Display(NotepadGray);

Comment: You may need to take a look at `CImage` [class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cimage-class?view=vs-2017)

Comment: I do not understand how to use CImage class, i'm newbi, An example would be very helpful...